# How can use tail for notifications above 0.99% loadav?

Tags: tail

```
#!/bin/bash

( tail -f -n0 /proc/loadavg 2> /dev/null & ) | grep -q "^[1-9]"
echo 'The millenium crystals are gunna blow!'
```

I though I was being clever and that would work. It just hangs and never reacts unless from run start and the first char is `[1-9]`

Comment: Just to nitpick: The load averages aren't percentages.

Answer (score 1):

`tail` does look for new lines, not for line chages:

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
      output appended data as the file grows;
```

If you want to verify this behaviour for yourself, you can use this command to change a line in `testfile`:

```
while true ; do
    sed "s/^.*$/$(date)/" -i testfile
    sleep 1
done
```

You could use a wile loop to check for line changes:

```
while true ; do
    grep -q "^[1-9]" /proc/loadavg && echo "$message"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can in conjunction use tail with grep for changes and not just new lines.

I just read before I came here that /proc/loadavg isn't actually a file but a kernel interface and maybe you are right, but even if it could I will still be up the swanny.

I was hoping for an inotify notification rather than the load of just constant loops but seems like computer says no.

Comment: I take it that something like Nagios is not on the table for this?

Comment: :) maybe not as nagios is likely doing the same and polling rather than using a tail inotify

Just means I can not use tail in a notification event scheme and will just have to use polling like ctx suggests